# iOS 8.0 - "failed to scene-update in time" crash

Tags: ios, ios8, crash-reports

I've encountered the following crash while running on iOS 8.0. This is the first time I'm seeing this so any observation will be helpful:

```
Incident Identifier: C39AF13A-D02B-40B1-8FC3-CFED8226D6FA
CrashReporter Key:   dace0b0fe53a1661c59ffa598b3a139a6177d713
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             Vieu [435]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/36CE6BFB-F90E-452B-8A4F-2B352F95DE48/Vieu.app/Vieu
Identifier:          com.vieu.mobile
Version:             140929 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-09-29 17:12:47.878 -0700
Launch Time:         2014-09-29 15:39:55.349 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.0.2 (12A405)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.vieu.mobile failed to scene-update in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 15.910 (user 15.910, system 0.000), 77% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 1.039, 5% CPU
```

- What does "failed to scene-update in time" mean?
- How can I reproduce these types of scenarios?
- What's the best approach to solve these in general?

Comment: are you taking a snapshot?  is it OpenGLES scene?  what are you up to  there?

Comment: There are no OpenGLES scenes, I'm not taking a snapshot of anything as far as I'm aware.

Comment: what does the app do in general

Comment: Automated video editing though in terms of video playblack I only use the standard MPMoviePlayerController

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, here's a hint. Apparently the notification message has changed from iOS 7.1 to iOS8.1

I got the same behavior/crash on my app as well and captured crash logs for each OS:

7.1 says:

```
Incident Identifier: 1AFAD8D6-50B3-4B5A-8EBE-2A76E4400BDA
CrashReporter Key:   8e228dccf0b7ae7d1127923c96eec86495483eae
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,3
Process:             ProcessName [2967]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/key/myApp.app
Identifier:          com.company.app
Version:             5.6.0042 (5.6)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]


Date/Time:           2014-11-04 17:32:57.089 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104


Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0


Application Specific Information:
com.company.app failed to resume in time
```

While iOS 8.1 says:

```
Incident Identifier: 960DB688-F165-4DCD-98A1-3F4AEFFB5442
CrashReporter Key:   2022d4aa4b6f69db15c58ae02734fb8172a77bba
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             ProcessName [175]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/key/myApp.app
Identifier:          com.company.app
Version:             5.6.0042 (5.6)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]


Date/Time:           2014-11-04 18:05:31.933 -0800
Launch Time:         2014-11-04 17:30:28.408 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B411)
Report Version:      105


Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0


Application Specific Information:
com.company.app failed to scene-update in time
```

So, pretty much everything is the same except for the Application Specific Information section.

In our case there was a method running on the Main thread that wasn't completing therefore it was getting the rest of the UI stuck and the system was killing it.As soon as we fixed that the problem went away on both versions.

So check what might be causing your Main thread to hang.