# CoreData Save Context Causing Crash When App Returns to Foreground. Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Okay so I am experiencing a frustrating issue that I would love some help or advice with.  Basically I have an app that I'm developing that utilizes `Core Data` to store numerous user properties.  What I have been doing for months during development, is I will save the `managedObjectContext` whenever the user transitions from active state to the background.  I use some background fetch requests, so I was a told to exclusively use the `applicationDidEnterBackground` in the `AppDelegate` instead the `applicationWillTerminate` function. Essentially I'm doing something similar to this:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

    if !userSaved {
        saveUserDataLocally()
    }

}

func saveUserDataLocally() {

    // Handle all the data, store it properly in managedObjectContext
    // .........
    // .......
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
        print("Success on save")
    } catch let error {
        print("Error saving user \(error)")
    }

}
```

Now this has been working just fine for months when I test the app on my iPhone through xCode. And it still works fine whenever I push the app into the background, and wait a few seconds for the save to the `managedObjectContext` to complete (sometimes it can take 3-4 seconds if there is a lot of data being stored).  My problem arises ONLY when I test the app NOT through xCode.  So if I have the app installed on my phone, and just try testing it while riding the bus to school I experience an issue.  And it only causes a crash when I push the app into background mode, and then instantly tap the app's icon on the home screen to launch it again (as if I accidentally tapped the home button to push it into the background). The same goes for if I'm not testing through xCode and try to force quit the app. In that circumstance it doesn't crash because the app isn't running, but it never completes the save.

I've tried tirelessly to recreate this problem while having my phone plugged into my computer and testing it through xCode, that way I could install break points and find the root of the issue. This problem NEVER exists when testing through xCode.  When I test it then, I can push the app to the background, and then half a second later launch it back up, and not only does the original save request complete, but it doesn't cause a crash.  Also I can force quit the app while running it through xCode and it will allow the save to complete, then the app will terminate.

As I'm sure you can imagine, this is very frustrating because if I can't recreate the problem while using the debugging tools xCode provides, I have a really hard time finding the source of the bug. Just to play it safe, I made sure numerous times that nothing is being called in the `AppDelegate`'s `applicationWillEnterForeground` or `applicationDidBecomeActive` methods.  I'm totally lost.  It seems to me that by pushing the app back to the foreground while it is in the middle of saving the `managedObjectContext`, it's getting confused and crashing...but then why doesn't that happen when I test the app on my device while using xCode?

Can anybody help me with this?  I may not have any hair left in a few hours! ;-)

|||   **UPDATE 06/03**   |||

So with the help of some commenters, I was able to find that part of the issue is due to the `CoreData` request clogging up the main thread, and then causing the app to stop responding.  I'm not sure that this is the exact solution to my specific problem, but is definitely helpful towards recognizing the issue completely.  One of the reasons I tried to do all my saving while transitioning into the background, was because I was executing all my saves on the main thread, and when I would perform a save during the app usage, it would cause a delay or bog down the main thread.  I've been experimenting with doing saves executing on a background thread, and it's helping tremendously.  Doing so, I can save my user data in the background while the other parts of the app are running, and it doesn't clog the main thread.  This helps make it so I don't even need to save while transitioning to background, so the crash won't happen anymore.

I found an amazing tutorial for executing background thread requests for `CoreData` by somebody named Justin Driscoll on themainthread.com

Check out this site if you are looking for help in executing `CoreData` requests in the background: http://themainthread.com/blog/2015/08/core-data-stack-in-swift.html

|||   **FURTHER UPDATE**   |||

For those who are possibly in need of help with a similar issue.  I used Mr. Driscoll's tutorial to create a `NSManagedObjectContext` that would save on a background thread. Even after I did everything, it was still executing everything on the main thread, and I was going insane.  I found one little thing that was very important: to make sure your save executes outside the main thread, set the proper concurrency type.  For example:

```
let concurrencyType:NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType = .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType

managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: concurrencyType)
```

Once I changed that one little thing, my save request would execute on the background thread and now my main thread was free to do UI updates and what not.  Hope this helps anybody experiencing similar frustrations!

Comment: put in a dummy time waster in place of the managedcontext store and see if the same problem occurs. see if it is related to core data or something else.

Comment: Well when I comment out the save request in `applicationDidEnterBackground`, and attempt to cause the crash, it returns to the foreground just fine.  So I assume that it is indeed something to do with `Core Data`, but I can't figure out why it works fine when run through xCode.

Comment: I think you're exceeding the time that the app is allowed to run in the background, and thus the crash.

Comment: @sschale ~ I get what you are saying, but that would still leave me confused, because if I tap the home button and wait about six seconds, then open the app back up it works fine.  It only crashes if I immediately try to re-open the app after pushing it into the background, and only when I'm not testing by running it through xCode.

Comment: Hmm, seems like it's hard to replicate. Have you taken a look at the device's crash logs? In the Xcode menus: Window -> Devices -> select your device -> View Device Logs (choose the All Logs tab)

Comment: @sschale ~ Thank you for that! I never knew about the device logs.  That is extremely helpful.  So what I can tell from looking at the numerous crash reports, they are all saying the same thing: "failed to scene-update after 10.00s".  I have no clue what that means

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337416/ios-8-0-failed-to-scene-update-in-time-crash - you may be running things on the main thread which causes a freakout. As a more general suggestion, you might consider doing saves throughout the use of the app instead of waiting until the end when it's very costly.

Comment: @sschale ~ Thank you for that reference! I'm pretty sure that you pointed me in the right direction. While testing, right now I have my app bogged down with numerous things it's saving to `CoreData` that is most likely taxing the main thread.  I will research how to run a save off the MT.  In the mean time, do you have any recommendations on tutorials for how to run a save request on a background thread? I know how to do it with like `CloudKit` using `dispatch_async`.  Is it the same with `CoreData`? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know how your core data stack is set up, but contexts are not thread safe. Take a look at having 2 contexts, one for main thread, one for saving. I personally use `MagicalRecord`, which does all the setup for me, but there's tons of tutorials out there. You can start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657437/core-data-background-context-best-practice